# jquery Orgchart multiple trees or orgcharts

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, orgchart

I am using the plugin from https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart. It does an excellent job of displaying a single org chart or hierarchy.

I would like to be able to "share" nodes between two trees. For example, I want node A from org chart 1 to move over to org chart 2.

My instantiation code (CoffeeScript is as follows:

```
$ ->
  $(".org1").jOrgChart
    dragAndDrop: true
    chartElement: "#chartArea1"

  $(".org2").jOrgChart
    dragAndDrop: true
    chartElement: "#chartArea2"
```

However, dragging an element from org1 to org 2 does not update either tree.
Note: If I put both trees under the same chartElement (i.e. div id="chartArea1"), only one tree is shown, that is why they are in different chartElements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Three charts (parentChart, chartArea1, chartArea2)
- Use dragAndDrop: true on parentChart
- Use chartArea1 and chartArea2 as children of parentChart